# Unexpected token in axios get request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm new to vue.js and trying to make GET call using axios but get an error:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
      name: 'AboutMe',

      data () {
        return {
              profile: {},
        }
      },

      computed: {
        token () {
          return this.$store.getters.getToken; 
        },
        BASE_URL () {
          return this.$store.state.BASE_URL;  
        }, 

        userid () {
          return  this.$store.getters.getUserid;
        }, 

      },

      created: {
        axios.get(this.BASE_URL + "/profile/aboutme/" + this.userid )
          .then( res => { 
            console.log.(res.data);

          })
          .catch( error => {   });
      }
    }
</script>
```

However I get this nasty error:

```
SyntaxError: /home/me/vue-myapp/src/components/AboutMe.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (121:9)

  119 | 
  120 |   created: {
> 121 |     axios.get(this.BASE_URL + "/profile/aboutme/" + this.userid )
      |          ^
  122 |       .then( res => { 
  123 |         console.log.(res.data);
  124 |
```

This is really confusing, as everything seems pretty normal. Appreciate your hints to fix this.

Comment: did you installed axios ? and imported it in your js file ?

Comment: Yes, it is installed, and imported as you see.

Comment: please try to import it as window.axios = require('axios'); in you js file

Comment: Hi you have created: { not created ()  {

Answer (score 1):

You have an unexpected `.` after `console.log.(res.data);`. It should be `console.log(res.data);`

The object is also malformed. It should be like:

```
 created: {
      axios.get(this.BASE_URL + "/profile/aboutme/" + this.userid )
      .then( res => { 
        console.log.(res.data);

      })
      .catch( error => {   })
  }
```

Comment: Well, I removed that extra dot but still get the error.

Comment: The object is malformed, remove the `;`

Comment: Still get the error. This may have some clue: `URIError: Failed to decode param '/%3C%=%20BASE_URL%20%%3Efavicon.ico'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
`

Comment: That is a different error, it related to your `vue.config.js`.  See this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1451

Comment: I've created the app using vue-cli and find no `vue.config.js` in my file structure. Any clues as to fix this? the github issue is unclear too.

Comment: i think you missing the main point. here its showing Unexpected token in axios get request. here an unexpected . placed. but if axios axist it will be normal. try to console log the axios object